# Using Java Lambdas like C++-style function pointers?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, function-pointers

I'm pretty new to lambdas and Java8 in general, so I apologize if this is a straightforward question.

I currently have a class that I want to do some intricate matching on that's final, with a bunch of getters:

```
public final class Foo {
  public String getName();
  public Type getType();
  public List<Bar> getBarList();
  ....
}
```

I've written a small helper class for matching:

```
public class MatchParameter<T> {
  boolean expectMatch = true;
  T valueToCheck;

  public MatchParameter(T value, boolean shouldMatch) {
    this.expectMatch = shouldMatch;
    this.valueToCheck = value;
  }

  public boolean matches(Predicate<T> matcher) {
    return matcher.test(valueToCheck) == expectMatch;
  }
}
```

I then have a place that creates various `MatchParameters` for things like checking the name, or checking that a the `List<Bar>` contains a particular `Bar`:

```
MatchParameter<String> nameParam = new MatchParameter(inputName, shouldMatch);
MatchParameter<Bar> barParam = new MatchParameter(inputBar, shouldMatch);
....
```

I'm currently stuck remembering what each `MatchParameter` is looking for. Eventually my check code looks like:

```
if(nameParam.matches(name -> currentFoo.getName().matches(name)) {
  ...
}
if(barParam.matches(bar -> currentFoo.getBarList().contains(bar)) {
  ...
}
...
```

In every case, the Predicate I'm passing is a lambda that has some iteration of `currentFoo.<accessorFns>` which eventually take a type T, and returns a boolean. What I'd really like to do is move the logic for the accessors to the creation of the MatchParameter.

Is there a way I can specify a function pointer that I can pass in at construction time? I'd expect it to be some sort of runnable that takes a `(Foo,T)`.

In C++ I'd add a local function pointer that took two inputs, a `Foo` and a `T`, to MatchParameter's local variables:

```
 bool (*checkFn)(Foo f, T input);
```

Then I could create an anonymous function for each instantiation, and update my MatchParameter `matches` implementation to be:

```
public boolean matches(Foo f) {
  return checkFn(f, valueToCheck) == expectMatch;
}
```

And my instantiation to be:

```
MatchParameter<String> nameParam = new MatchParameter<>(
  inputName, 
  shouldMatch, 
  (Foo f, String input) -> boolean { return f.getName().matches(input); }
);
```

Is there equivalent way to achieve this in Java?

Comment: Sure.  Create an interface that accepts a `Foo` and a `T` and returns a `boolean`.  Accept that in your constructor.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're doing, but why do you need the `MatchParameter` class? It looks like it's just adding more bulk to a basic `if` statement.

Comment: The first parameter is redundant if you're defining the predicate at the same time. Why not `new MatchParameter<>(shouldMatch, f -> f.getname().matches(inputName))`?

Comment: @shmosel You're absolutely right in this context hah. I significantly simplified it from my actual code, and the `MatchParameter` actually needs to know about the value it's matching for its other (unlisted in my example) functions as well. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function should always return a boolean, then you can pass a `BiPredicate` to the constructor:

```
public class MatchParameter<T> {
    boolean expectMatch = true;

    T valueToCheck;

    BiPredicate<Foo, T> predicate;

    public MatchParameter(T value, boolean shouldMatch, BiPredicate<Foo, T> function) {
        this.expectMatch = shouldMatch;
        this.valueToCheck = value;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    public boolean matches(Predicate<T> matcher) {
        return matcher.test(valueToCheck) == expectMatch;
    }
}
```

You can then instantiate the object as follows:

```
MatchParameter<String> nameParam = new MatchParameter<>(inputName, shouldMatch,
    (foo, input) -> f.getName().matches(input)
);
```

Finally, you can create a function to test the `BiPredicate` to a `Foo` object:

```
public boolean matches(Foo f) {
    return predicate.test(f, valueToCheck) == expectMatch;
}
```

Comment: `BiPredicate` would be a better fit.

Comment: What do you mean by "anonymous function"?

Comment: I'm not sure, I mostly copied the term from the OP but it's incorrect in this context.

Comment: BiPredicate (and your original BiFunction) are exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!  The `BiFunction` would be useful if you were returning a type other a `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `MatchParameter` class is pointless, since there's no need to encapsulate neither the given input value nor the condition. Instead, I would just create a `Predicate<Foo>` based on a condition over some property of `Foo` that needs to match a given input value. This could be achieved with a static method that receives:

- An extractor for the attribute, which would actually be a [`Function<Foo, U>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)
- A [`BiPredicate<U, V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html) that receives both the extracted attribute (of type `U`) and an input value (of type `V`) to check against
- The input value

The return value of this static method would be a `Predicate<Foo>`. Here's the code:

```
public static <T, U, V> Predicate<T> matchesFor(
    Function<T, U> extractor,
    BiPredicate<U, V> condition,
    V inputValue,
    boolean shouldMatch) {

    return t -> condition.test(extractor.apply(t), inputValue) == shouldMatch;
}

// A handy overload
public static <T, U, V> Predicate<T> matchesFor(
    Function<T, U> extractor,
    BiPredicate<U, V> condition,
    V inputValue) {

    return matchesFor(extractor, condition, inputValue, true);
}
```

Then, wherever you were creating the matchers, use the `matchesFor` method instead:

```
Predicate<Foo> nameMatcher = matchesFor(
    Foo::getName,    // if Foo's name
    String::matches, // matches
    SOME_REGEX);     // this specific input regex

Predicate<Foo> barsMatcher = matchesFor(
    Foo::getBarList, // if Foo's Bar list
    List::contains,  // contains
    SOME_BAR);       // this specific input Bar
```

Finally, within your loop, simply use the predicates created above:

```
if (nameMatcher.test(currentFoo)) {
    // ...
}

if (barsMatcher.test(currentFoo)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How is that better than `if (currentFoo.getName().matches(SOME_REGEX))`?

Comment: I think it's more a presentation problem

Comment: It could be useful to encapsulate the matcher data in a single object, but your example doesn't really demonstrate that.

Comment: Also, it sounds like OP's real use case is more complex, so it may not be possible to restructure. See my own [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926295/using-java-lamdas-like-c-style-function-pointers/43926637?noredirect=1#comment74886003_43926295) to the question.

Comment: This still seems a little unnecessary. What's wrong with simple predicate `foo -> foo.getName().matches(SOME_REGEX)`? OP seems to be focused on separating the test value (`input`) from the predicate, while your solution separates the predicate from the its target attribute (`foo.name`), which doesn't seem to be the intent. As a side note, Guava offers very similar functionality with [`Predicates.compose()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#compose-com.google.common.base.Predicate-com.google.common.base.Function-).

Comment: That's exactly why he needs the `MatchParameter` class - to encapsulate the test value.

Comment: @shmosel I have modified my answer to take your comments into account. I still hold that there's no need for the `MatchParameter` class, however I changed the `matchesFor` method to support matching against an up-front given input value, as you suggested.